# Vertically middle align label radio button

Tags: html, css, sass, radio-button, text-alignment

I have created custom radio buttons which looks really good. Just having small issue with label vertical alignment. I want label should be vertically middle aligned but its seems top aligned. I have been playing from long time with `line-height` and `vertical-align` property but nothing seems to be working.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dipaktelangre/2L3x4y8u/) in scss.

Current (Not expected)
[image]

Update : If i add `align-items:center` as suggested then radio dot position get changed as text size grows. example updated.

```css
.btn-radio {
     position: relative;
     margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
     line-height: 1;
}

 input[type="radio"] {
     display: none; 
}
 label {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
     text-align: left;
     align-items:center;
}
 input[type="radio"] + label {
     cursor: pointer;
     margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
 input[type="radio"] + label:before {
     content: "";
     display: inline-block;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     margin-right: 5px;
     border: 2px solid #adb5bd;
     background-color: white;
     border-radius: 50%;
     vertical-align: middle;
}
 input[type="radio"].disabled + label, input[type="radio"]:disabled + label {
     background-color: #f8f9fa;
     opacity: 0.5;
     cursor: not-allowed;
}
 input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
     background-color: #007a9d;
     border-color: #007a9d;
}
 input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     left: 8px;
     top: 8px;
     width: 9px;
     height: 9px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background-color: white;
}
```

```html
 <div class="btn-radio">
    <input class="radio-sm" type="radio" name="sizeRadios" id="sizeRadios1" value="option1" checked />
    <label class="" for="sizeRadios1">
      Radio button
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-radio">
    <input class="radio-sm" type="radio" name="sizeRadios" id="sizeRadios2" value="option2" checked />
    <label class="" for="sizeRadios2">
      This is long text for radio button, I know this can not be that long in real life but with for radio can be short so it should warp content correctly.
    </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Well, I think you got your answer, so if it works for you, please mark it as an answer. Otherwise please tell us why the provided answers do not work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make them centre by adding [`align-items: center;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Box_Alignment_in_CSS_Grid_Layout) to your `<label>` element. It will make the element vertically centre.

So your final code should be something like this:

```css
.btn-radio {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  line-height: 1;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  align-items: center;
}

input[type="radio"]+label {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

input[type="radio"]+label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #adb5bd;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type="radio"].disabled+label,
input[type="radio"]:disabled+label {
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label:before {
  background-color: #007a9d;
  border-color: #007a9d;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  top: 8px;
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-radio">
  <input class="radio-sm" type="radio" name="sizeRadios" id="sizeRadios1" value="option1" checked />
  <label class="" for="sizeRadios1">
      Radio button
    </label>
</div>

<div class="btn-radio">
  <input class="radio-sm" type="radio" name="sizeRadios" id="sizeRadios2" value="option2" checked />
  <label class="" for="sizeRadios2">
      This is long text radio button
    </label>
</div>
```

## UPDATE

Well, the updated problem that you provide here is a different kind from the original one and it does not relate to `align-items: center;` and other stuff. But I will explain why it's happening and what you should do to fix it.

### What is happening here?

Elements with position `absolute` will be count out of normal page layout so defining them in this way will make things go weird unexpectedly.

### How to fix it?

To fix such a matter you need to make them respective to their parents instead of document `body`. And to do so you should simply make the parent element position, `relative`. Then in your particular case, there is no need to specify the `top` element since `align-items` will take care of its vertical position.

So your final code should be something like this:

```css
.btn-radio {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  line-height: 1;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  align-items: center;
}

input[type="radio"]+label {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

input[type="radio"]+label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #adb5bd;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type="radio"].disabled+label,
input[type="radio"]:disabled+label {
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label:before {
  background-color: #007a9d;
  border-color: #007a9d;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-radio">
  <input class="radio-sm" type="radio" name="sizeRadios" id="sizeRadios1" value="option1" checked />
  <label class="" for="sizeRadios1">
    Radio button
  </label>
</div>

<div class="btn-radio">
  <input class="radio-sm" type="radio" name="sizeRadios" id="sizeRadios2" value="option2" checked />
  <label class="" for="sizeRadios2">
    This is long text for radio button, I know this can not be that long in real life but with for radio can be short so it should warp content correctly.
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: this creates issue for dot position of radio button for long text label. updated question.

Comment: @DipakTelangre Well, your current issue is not relative to the previous one and it's totally a different question but I provide an update for your situation.